# Move all files of a certain name using command line

Tags: file, command-line, command, command-prompt, move

What I am trying to do is to move folders of only a specific name from subdirectories into a new location (say, from `C:\users\me\desktop\animals` to `C:\users\me\desktop\folder2` ) using the command line.  For example:

Essentially, let's say I have an Animals folder, with three subfolders: `Birds`, `Mammals`, and `Reptiles` as follows:

```
Animals
  Birds
    Breathe
      more subdirectories
    Feathers
      more subdirectories
  Mammals
    Fur
      more subdirectories
    Breathe
      more subdirectories
  Reptiles:
    Breathe
      more subdirectories
    Scales
      more subdirectories
```

I want to copy the `Breathe` folder and its subdirectories from `Mammals`, `Reptiles`, AND `birds` (which are all within the Animals folder).  How can I accomplish this?

So far I've been able to iterate through files with

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b C:\users\me\desktop\folder1') do move "breathe"
```

but this only returns this error 3 times:

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I understand why, but how can I fix this such that it actually enters each folder and copies what I care about?

Comment: Try `dir /B /S /A:D C:\users\me\desktop\animals\Breathe`. Then, parse it in a `for` loop as follows: `for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir …') do @ECHO move "%~f"`. Remove `ECHO` no sooner than debugged!